# Is it best practice to set state attributes to undefined in the constructor?

Tags: reactjs

I am coming in on a React project that sets state to undefined and I feel like this may not be best practice. Is it possible that if something attempts to access an undefined state it could throw errors? Would it be better to have the state be initialized with empty values? Maybe I am making the wrong assumption here.

```
class MyClass extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      foo: undefined,
      bar: undefined,
      foobar: undefined
    };
  }
```

Comment: Read somewhere in the docs that initial value we might set to `null` instead of `undefined` in react.

Comment: Is there any concern of the errors that might occur if the state is accessed before it is updated when the values are null or undefined?

Comment: @JamesCourcelle of course, if you're expecting `this.state.foo` to be an array, but it's initial value is `undefined` or `null`, when you try to access some of array's methods, such as `map`, it will throw an error. This applies to other types as well, such as strings, numbers, etc. You have to handle those cases.

Comment: I would personally use ```null``` instead of ```undefined```, but I rarely ever do that in my state anyway.  I usually go with something like Muhammad's answer in my code, and would probably be the best route to go.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than initializing the `state` with `undefined`, it's better to initialize it with expected empty values. Let say you have:

```
state:{
  orders: undefined,
  balance: undefined
}
```

Now, if you want to render `orders` as:

```
{this.state.orders.map(order => {
  return <p>{order.details}</p>;
})}
```

The above code will break and you are probably going to see an error saying *can't find map on undefined*. So, to avoid such breaks and render something on screen it is better to initialize with empty values like:

```
state:{
  orders: [],
  balance: 0
}
```

The above code wouldn't break and view will be rendered. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Okay this is what I thought would occur thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Initializing the state like this makes some difference, for example when you want to iterate through all of its keys. However, it is a good practice to initialize all state elements in constructor, for clarity's sake. It is way more readable to be able to see what keys are handled by the state.

Comment: Okay this may make sense then. So as long as you make sure that you set each element in something like the componentDidMount() we don't need to be worried about the undefined state? Am I worrying about the undefined state for no reason?